# Filling Missing values with specified Format

Tags: python

I have a problem to solve which is to fill missing value in a specific format

Input:

```
"_,_,30,_,_,_,50,_,_"
```

Output:

```
10,10,12,12,12,12,4,4,4
```

we will fill the missing values from left to right

1. first we will distribute the 30 to left two missing values `(10, 10, 10, _, _, _, 50, _, _)`
2. now distribute the sum (10+50) missing values in between `(10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, _, _)`
3. now we will distribute 12 to right side missing values `(10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 4, 4, 4)`

i am only able to solve till a certain level.

```
s="_,_,30,_,_,_,50,_,_"
s1=s.split(",")
print(s1)
print('**************')

w=[]

for i in s1:
    if i=='_':
        w.append(0)
    else:
        w.append(int(i))
print(w)

print('*****************')

x=w[0:3]
y=w[3:]

print(x)
print('**********')
print(y)
print('***********')

avg=int(np.mean(x))
print(avg)
print('********')

c=list(map(lambda x: avg,x) )

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to fill (always is a good idea to modularize the code you write):

```
from typing import List


def fill_missing_values(s: str) -> str:
    s1: List[str] = s.split(',')
    first_num_value: int = 0
    start_at: int = s1.index('_')
    end_at: int = 0
    for index, value in enumerate(s1[start_at:]):
        end_at = index
        if value.isdigit():
            first_num_value = int(value)
            break
    # Now you can replace values
    start_at = 0 if start_at == 0 else start_at - 1
    end_at += 0 if start_at == 0 else start_at + 1
    previous_value: int = 0 if start_at == 0 else int(s1[start_at])
    range_len: int = (end_at - start_at + 1) if start_at == 0 else (end_at - start_at + 1)
    new_value: float = (first_num_value + previous_value) / range_len
    for index in range(start_at, end_at+1):
        s1[index] = new_value
    return ','.join([str(x).replace('.0', '') for x in s1])
```

And then just call it in a loop:

```
s: str = "_,_,30,_,_,_,50,_,_"
matches = ['_,', ',_,', ',_']
index: int = 1
while any(x in s for x in matches):
    s = fill_missing_values(s)
    print('step {}: {}'.format(index, s))  # this is to show temporarily status, you can remove it
    index += 1
print(s.split(','))
```

In this case i printed the output in the console.

```
step 1: 10,10,10,_,_,_,50,_,_
step 2: 10,10,12,12,12,12,12,_,_
step 3: 10,10,12,12,12,12,4,4,4
['10', '10', '12', '12', '12', '12', '4', '4', '4']
```

Answer (score -1):

You said its going to be a special format. So I'm assuming 30 and 50 stands for index[2] and index[7]. So, here is my solution to it. If you are saying 30 and 50 are always exist in the list but their index is not constant you just need to use `s.index()` function to find the index and use that index to get the new count and value.
Here is the code:

```
s = "_,_,30,_,_,_,50,_,_"
s = s.split(",")  
result = []
count = s.index('30') + 1
value = int(s[2]) / count
while count > 1:
    result.append(str(int(value)))
    count -= 1
value = int((value + int(s[6])) / (6 - 2 + 1))
count = 6 - 2 + 1
while count > 1:
    result.append(str(value))
    count -= 1
value = int(value / (len(s) - 6))
count = len(s) - 6
while count > 0:
    result.append(str(value))
    count -= 1
print(result)
```

Comment: it's not always 30,50 will be in the list it can be any no and in any position except 1st and last (0,n-1).

Comment: Yes, so I used index here, then you just need to use the first and second non "_" characters' index instead of the indexes of  30 and 50.